# Twilio Api - Get number of minutes for a number

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I'm trying to get the total number of minutes for outbound calls from a specific twilio number. The twilio account I use has dozens of numbers. So far I've managed to get the total of minutes for all the numbers but I haven't found a way to filter by phone number. Anny suggestions?

```
<?php
// Download the library and copy into the folder containing this file.
require('../twilio-php-latest/Services/Twilio.php');

$account_sid = "xxxx"; // Your Twilio account sid
$auth_token = "xxxx"; // Your Twilio auth token
$client = new Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token);

$record = $client->account->usage_records->today->getCategory('calls-outbound');
echo $record->usage ;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer : Retrieving stats by phone number is not possible

While the Usage API should be able to supply the necessary data for most use cases, it is not yet able to provide usage by phone number.

https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-basics/how-can-i-see-my-twilio-data